# Get objects with similar foreign key

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

This is a basic question that probably has been asked before, but after searching quite a time, I couldn't find the answer. I'm not very familiar with the terminology in Django yet, so I've probably searched for the wrong phrases.

To the question: I currently have 3 different models:

```
League
Team (foreign key=League)
Match(foreign key=League)
```

My goal is to add a choice list in the `Match` model where all teams which have the same primary key as the Match instance is listed. I'm not sure if I am attacking this problem the right way - the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) says that `choice` should be limited to static values

Later on, I want to reference the chosen team inside the `Match` class.

Below is the models I've written so far.

```
class League(models.Model):
    league_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    max_teams = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.league_name


class Team(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(League)
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.team_name


class Match(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(League)
    teams = {team.team_name: team for team in Team.objects.filter(pk=league)}
    home_team = models.CharField(choices=teams)
```

When executing `python manage.py syncdb`, I get a pretty long traceback, but the code it questions is

```
teams = {team.team_name: team for team in Team.objects.filter(pk=league)}
```

Traceback:

```
(...)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ForeignKey'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what choices are for - apart from anything else, that definition is at the class level, and is evaluated well before you've instantiated the object whose league you're hoping to use.

`home_team` should be a ForeignKey to Team. The best way to constrain the choices of teams to the relevant league is to do it in the form, rather than in the model.

Comment: This seems reasonable. Would you mind elaborating a bit on when to use `choices`? I find the documentation a bit confusing.

Comment: You can basically think of choices as an enum: a mapping of codes to strings for a collection of values which don't depend on anything else, like gender or title in a Person class.

Comment: Should I consider using a many-to-one relationship between Match and Team? When using your code, I get an error complaining about that I have too many ForeignKey() listed, and it suggest that I add a `related_name` attribute to the foreign key.

Comment: Nevermind, I understood the problem after running `python manage.py sql appname`. Thank you for your help.